# Python Dictionary Maps NaN's Instead of Contents

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, mapping

I have a pandas dataframe with several real estate listings. A subset of the dataset is as follows.

```
Neighborhood      High School      ...
WOODLEY           LIBERTY
WOODLEY 
COUNTRY CLUB  
COUNTRY CLUB      HERITAGE
COUNTRY CLUB      HERITAGE
COUNTRY CLUB      TUSCORORA
...
```

Many of the neighborhoods have no information and others are incorrect. I am trying to do a mapping to rectify this.

```
cleanHS = {"WOODLEY": "LIBERTY", "COUNTRY CLUB": "HERITAGE", ...}
dirty["High School"] = dirty["High School"].map(cleanHS)
```

Unfortunately, this results in the `High School` column having only `NaN`'s. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dirty["High School"] = dirty["Neighborhood"].map(cleanHS)`

If you are mapping high school to high school, you will not receive the desired result. High school district is derived from neighborhood, so you need to ensure the two columns are interacting.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are mapping the values from `High School` to other values, but your starting column from which to map values should be `Neighborhood`

```
dirty["High School"] = dirty["Neighborhood"].map(cleanHS)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the column which you are trying to map

```
dirty["High School"] = dirty["Neighborhood"].map(cleanHS)
```